# KeyCloak resource_ access containing multiple resources

Tags: security, oauth, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm currently studying OIDC and KeyCloak but i'm not really understanding the nature of access token. I created two clients (authz-test and app_authz_2) and assigned different roles to users accessing the resource, then I authenticated and requested authorization on app_authz_2 but I can see the `resource_access` claim also includes roles for authz-test.

```
 "resource_access": {
   "authz-test": {
     "roles": [
       "watcher_role"
     ]
   },
   "app_2_authz": {
     "roles": [
       "app_2_role"
     ]
   },
   "account": {
     "roles": [
       "manage-account",
       "manage-account-links",
       "view-profile"
     ]
   }
 },
```

This resource_access claim is what i'm talking about. My fear is that access token will eventually bloat with resource access claims so I'm asking if is possible and if it's a good practice to not include resource_access claims of different resource servers.

Comment: I guess used OIDC client has `Full Scope Allowed` enabled, so you see all resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an out-of-the-box installation, newly created clients get assigned a default client scope called `roles`. If you look at that client scope, you will see a mapper called `client roles` of type `User Client Role`.
Since this mapper does not have a specific client configured, all client roles from all clients will be encoded into the token by default.

You may want to consider unassigning the default `roles` client scope from your client and assign a mapper of type `User Client Role` to your clients instead that only map the client roles of that particular client.

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally solved my problem. Is it a good practice to remove all clients access role though?